# Percent sign at the end of the output of python script

Tags: python, command-line, stdout

Why is a percent sign at the end of the output of the python script?

$ echo "TEST TEST" | trim
TESTTEST%

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(''.join(line.split()))
```

Comment: The Problem is solved, zsh prompts with % when the command which is executed doesn't print a newline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%` you see there might actually be your shell prompt, and not part of your program output. You're not writing a new line after your output, so the shell prompt appears at the very end of the output of the last command.

Possible solutions:

1. Use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write`
2. Append a newline to the end of the output with `+ "\n"`
3. Add a `print()` to the end of your program

Comment: I correct it with an `+"\n"` and it did the job. Thanks